# TypeError: Cannot read property 'page' of undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing admin page of shop.
this admin page login members like that: develop, shop, seller
When I log in with develop, it shows up well. shop also shows up well, but when I log in with seller got this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'page' of undefined in react.

anyone can help?

```
export const withPagination = (selector, action) => (WrappedComponent) => {
  class __Pagination extends React.PureComponent {
    static propTypes = {
      ...baseProps
    }

    setData = (data) => {
      const last = this._data
      this._data = data
      if (!_.isEqual(data, last)) {
        this.handleFetchData(this._lastState)
      }
    }

    handleFetchData = (state) => {
      this._lastState = state
      const { page, pageSize, sorted, filtered } = state
      this.props.getListData({ page, pageSize, sorted, filtered, data: this._data })
    }

    render() {
      const { props } = this
      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          {...props}
          handleFetchData={this.handleFetchData}
          setData={this.setData}
        />
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: handleFetchData from your WrappedComponent may not be passing state as argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the snippet given and with problem statement the only possibility is - 
when try with 'seller' - page property is not present in the state object when passed to handleFetchData method's parameter.

One small suggestion : while using destructuring on - 
const { page, pageSize, sorted, filtered } = state

User some default values like this - 
const { page = 0, pageSize = 0, sorted = false, filtered = false} = state;
This is just for example not sure about the data types.

Comment: In the function handleFetchData, console.log(state) and see if it is set.

Comment: Thanks for u r comment . I just edit my code like this:

Comment: handleFetchData = (state) => {
      this._lastState = state
      this.props.getListData({...state, data: this._data })
    }

Comment: now it shows up well, can u feedback for my code ? it is right or not?